# CSSが順番どおりに適用されない

Tags: javascript, html, css

[Materialize](http://materializecss.com/)というCSSライブラリを使っています。
HTMLのheadで下記のようにMaterializeをCDNから最初に、自分のCSSファイルを後に読み込んでいます。

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/css/materialize.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/styles.css">
```

Chromeで確認すると`materialize.min.css`が先に取得され、その後に`styles.css`が取得されています。

しかし、`styles.css`で`materialize.min.css`の属性を上書きしても、`materialize.min.css`の属性が適用されてしまいます。具体的には下記のCSSを`styles.css`に追加したところ、この状況になりました。

```
.card-content{
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

後に読み込まれた方のCSSで上書きされると考えていましたが、このようなことはなぜおこるのでしょうか。また、後に読み込まれたCSSで上書きするにはどのようにすればいいのでしょうか。

Comment: 実際に確認していませんが、基本的に後のもので上書きされるというのは正しいです。この場合`materialize.min.css`のものがより特定されたものであるため適用されないということだと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.card-content`に対して`max-height`が設定されているのは[_cards.scss](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/5b75e62d50598ce6446273f9a78a43e14f193d1f/sass/components/_cards.scss#L37-L38)ですが正確には

```
.card {
    &.small, &.medium, &.large {
        .card-content {
            max-height: 40%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    }
}
```

となっていて最終的な`materialize.min.css`にも

```
.card.small .card-content,.card.medium .card-content,.card.large .card-content{max-height:40%;overflow:hidden}
```

と書かれています。ですのでこれを上書きしたいのであれば

```
.card.small .card-content, .card.medium .card-content, .card.large .card-content{
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

などのように記述する必要があります。

Answer (score 2):

すでに解決していますが、補足させていただきます。

CSSの適用順序は、読み込み順序の他に、詳細度による順序があります。

http://buburinweb.wp.xdomain.jp/css-detailing

今回は、ライブラリ側で `.card.small .card-content` という指定になっているため、
詳細度の低い `.card-content` では上書きできませんでした。

従って、以下のように指定すれば、上書きできました。
- `.hoge .card-content`
- `#hoge .card-content`